# populate php array with while loop?

Tags: php, arrays, sqlite, loops

Is there a way to output an sqlite table to a php array?

I am currently trying to use a while loop but it does not display correctly.

```
$db = sqlite_open ("products.db", 0666, $error);
$result=sqlite_query($db,"SELECT * from Books");
$products = array();
while($row=sqlite_fetch_array($result,SQLITE_ASSOC))
{
    $products = $row;
}
```

I want this to store into a 2D php array as if it were:

```
$products = array(
    1 => array(
        'name' => '',
        'price' => ,
        'category' => '',
        'description' => ''
    ),
    2 => array(
        'name' => '',
        'price' => ,
        'category' => '',
        'description' => ''
    ),
    3 => array(
        'name' => '',
        'price' => ,
        'category' => '',
        'description' => ''
    )
);
```

Comment: use an array assignment, every iteration, its overwritten, you could also use your ID as the key in assignment `$products[$row['id']]` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close. You just need to add each row to your array instead of overwriting the array variable which you are currently doing..

```
while($row=sqlite_fetch_array($result,SQLITE_ASSOC))
{
    $products[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this has fixed the issue!